# Multiple Playa fields in Channel Form not updating

Tags: matrix, playa, channel-form

I am using {exp:zoo_visitor:update_form> on a rather large Profile page for members to update their details.

It seems that you can only update one playa field at the time - I have experimented wrapping the {exp:zoo_visitor:update_form> tags around all form entries and each separate but the Playa fields don't update together.

---

**Update**: I replaced all Playa fields with the native Relationships field (yikes!) but these fields seem to hold the data. There is also a Matrix field, which doesn't hold the data but after replacing this with the native Grid field it's behaviour maintains.

Surely this is all JS related but I am not able to debug this....

include_jquery="no" has no effect.

---

### Running 2.7.3

Comment: Is this an {exp:zoo_visitor:update_form} or an {exp:channel:form}? (Or both? I’ve never used Visitor so I’m not familiar with how the update form works.) There’s definitely no reason why you can’t have two separate Playa fields saved in the same Channel Form; many people have done it.

Comment: This is a {exp:zoo_visitor:update_form} but same happens when testing with {exp:channel:form}. After separating the Playa and Matrix fields from all other custom fields the form behaves as expected. Might be the {member_photo} which messes with them.

Answer (score 1):

**FYI:** pushed by the need to keep using Matrix & Playa and not having to deal with the ugliness of the native Grid & Relationships fields (what were they thinking?) I resolved this issue by separating the Matrix and Playa fields into another template.

Convinced that these issues are caused by too many different jQuery calls and sequencing these correctly might resolve these issues.

The Profile page will require a small UI change, adding some sub navigation to the second template.